# Create new column in pandas which is the value of specific location from list

Tags: python, pandas, list, slice

I have dataframe similar to the following:

```
>>>index    val
0    5      1231
1    3      741
2    0      132
3    8      912
....
```

In addition to that, I have the following list:

```
lst=['day',605.12,607.34,609.11,611.3,613.45,617.4,618.9,621.2...]
```

I want to create new column in my dataframe, so the value in the new column will come from the position in the "index" column, so the result should look like this:

```
>>>index    val     value_from_list
0    5      1231       613.45
1    3      741        609.11
2    0      132        'day'
3    8      912        621.2
....
```

I have tried to do something like this:

```
df['value_from_list']=lst[df['index']]
```

but that not correct and gives error

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Series

How can I get the new column values from the list based on the index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try via `pd.Series()` and `map()`:

```
df['val_from_list']=df['index'].map(pd.Series(lst))
#you can also use replace() method in place of map()
```

**OR**

via `pd.Series()` and `merge()`:

```
df=df.merge(pd.Series(lst).reset_index(name='val_from_list'),on='index')
```

Comment: @jezrael can you explain more on that? To my knowledge, ```map``` as well as ```merge``` are ```O(n)``` as well and not parallel by default either? Am I wrong?

Comment: @FloLie Because apply are loops under the hood, so from all 3 solutions it is not vectorized.

Answer (score 2):

I think using the `apply` function is the simplest solution in this case

```
import pandas as pd
d = [{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":3,"b":4}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

l = [10,20]

df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: l[x.name], axis=1)
```

```
Out[1]: 
   a  b  new
0  1  2   10
1  3  4   20
```

Answering my own question regarding the speed difference between the proposed solutions, indeed the `map` version is may far the fastest. Test environment:

```
import pandas as pd
from random import random
from time import time
size = 10000000

test_df = pd.DataFrame([{'index': random(), 'l': random()} for i in range(size)])
test_list = [random() for i in range(size)]


def map_version(df, l):
    df['val_from_list']=df['index'].map(pd.Series(l))

def merge_version(df, l):
    df=df.merge(pd.Series(l).reset_index(name='val_from_list'),on='index')

def apply_version(df, l):
    df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: l[x.name], axis=1)
    
    

start_time = time()
map_version(test_df,test_list)
print("Map Version: ",time()-start_time)
start_time = time()
merge_version(test_df,test_list)
print("Merge Version: ",time()-start_time)
start_time = time()
apply_version(test_df,test_list)
print("Apply Version: ",time()-start_time)
```

Result for n= 10⁸:

```
Map Version:  17.509589910507202
Merge Version:  23.45218276977539
Apply Version:  37.030272483825684
```